# Printing all variants of a word

Tags: c, passwords, generator

So here is the the program which i am trying to make:
Create password generator, which uses dictionary and match files to generate passwords by replacing letters in the dictionary words with their matches.
Example:
Dictionary file:
apple
loop
Match file:
a 4
e 3
o 0
Output:
4pple
appl3
4ppl3
l0op
lo0p
l00p

And this is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* function prototypes */
int read_source(char* ,char* ,char* );
char* shift_string(char* ,char* );
int write_shifted(char* ,char* );

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* argv[1]: the source file with the original strings
 * argv[2]: the shift file which indicates which characters are to be
 * replaced with what
 * argv[3]: the file in which the new strings are to be stored*/

if(!argv[1])
{
    printf("No source file, can do nothing. Exiting.\n");
    return 1;
}
else if (!argv[2])
{
    printf("No shift file given, can do nothing. Exiting.\n");
    return 2;
}
else if (!argv[3])
{
    /* If no output file has been specified, print the
     * output directly to the console. */
    read_source(argv[1],argv[2],NULL);
    return 0;
}

if (read_source(argv[1],argv[2],argv[3])!=0)
{
    printf("There has been an error. Exiting.\n");
    return 3;
}

if (argv[3])
{
    printf("Everything seems to have gone according to plan.\n");
    printf("Your output has been stored in \"%s\"\n",argv[3]);
}

return 0;
}

int read_source(char* source_file,char* shift_file,char* out_file)
{
FILE *file_pointer;
file_pointer=fopen(source_file, "r");

/* Exit gracefully if source_file cannot be found. */
if (file_pointer == NULL) 
{
     printf("Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading.\n",source_file);
     return 1;
}

char* new_line;

    /* maximum line length, can be changed if needed */
char line[256];

/* Go through the source file. */
while (fgets(line,sizeof line,file_pointer) != NULL)
{
    new_line = shift_string(shift_file,line);
    if (new_line==NULL)
    {
        printf("There has been an error with replacing the characters.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    write_shifted(new_line,out_file);
}
int fclose(FILE *file_pointer);

return 0;
 }


 char* shift_string(char* shift_file,char* source_string)
 {
/* This function replaces certain characters in a given source_string as
 * specified by shift_file */


/* Open shift file. */
FILE *file_pointer;
char i,j;
file_pointer=fopen(shift_file, "r");

/* Exit gracefully if shift_file cannot be found. */
if (file_pointer == NULL) 
{
     printf("Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading.\n",shift_file);
     return NULL;
}

int k;

/* Determine how long the source_string is for the loop below. */
int length = strlen(source_string);

while (fscanf(file_pointer, "%c %c\n", &i, &j)==2)
{

    /* This loop actually does the replacing. */
    for (k=0;k<length;k++)
    {
        if (source_string[k]==i) 
        {
            source_string[k]=j;
        }
    }
}
int fclose(FILE *file_pointer);

return source_string;
}

int write_shifted(char* new_line,char* out_file)
{
/* This function writes the new strings to out_file
 * If no out_file has been given, it will write the
 * output to the console.*/

if (out_file==NULL)
{
    printf("%s",new_line);
    return 0;
}

FILE *file_pointer; 

/* Open in a+ mode. If out_file does not yet exist, it will be created.
 * If it does exist, it will be appended to instead of overwritten. */
file_pointer = fopen(out_file,"a+"); 

/* Write the new line */
fprintf(file_pointer,"%s",new_line);

fclose(file_pointer);
return 0; 
}
```

So the problem is that now it prints only the final states (4ppl3 l00p) but i also need the middle states (4pple appl3 l0op lo0p). Can someone give me some clues how to make it. thanks in advance. :)

Comment: wrong check `!argv[n]`

Comment: the standard requires that argv is `argv[argc] == NULL`, but there is case of no true.

Answer (score 0):

recursion works well for this type of problem.  Basically, take whether or not to have the first letter substituted, and recurse with the rest of the word for each case - substituted and not substituted.  Do this until you don't have any letters left, and you'll have all your combinations.

```
// terribly pseudo-codey, but should give the idea
string='abc';
stringfunction("", string);

// simplified, just shifts each letter by one
stringfunction(processed, unprocessed)
  if unprocessed is empty
    print processed
    return

  stringfunction(strcat(processed, unprocessed[0]), unprocessed[1]);
  stringcunction(strcat(processed, unprocessed[0]+1), unprocessed[1]);
```

this will print out abc, abd, acc, acd, bbc, bbd, bcc, bcd

of course, for your case, instead of shifting the letter, you'd either do or not do the substitution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it. But i am still not sure how to implement the recursion. Can you be more specific? Sorry for the trouble.